# Como fazer menu dropdown no Angular com Materialize CSS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular, typescript, materialize

Estava fazendo um pequeno projeto com Angular (v8.2.5) e Materialize (materialize-css v1.0.0), e decidi, em determinado momento, inserir um menu dropdown em um componente header. Seguindo o modelo da documentação, meu HTML ficou assim:

```
<div class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
  <ul>
    <li><a>item1</a></li>
    <li><a>item2</a></li>
    <li><a>item3</a></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-trigger" target="dropdown1">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'user']" size="lg"></fa-icon>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Porém, ao fazer o Typescript, não sei qual lugar é o correto para chamar o jQuery do exemplo, e fiz isso:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

/* trecho omitido */
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  /* trecho omitido */

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      $("#dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
    });
  }
}
```

Porém, o typescript não reconhece a função dropdown (https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html), e o sistema não executa a ação correspondente. O que devo fazer?

Comment: E qual erro é retornado? Lembrando que não é muito aconselhado utilizar jQuery junto com Angular, cada um manipula o Dom a seu modo e isso pode gerar muitos bugs, além de mais N motivos, mas, as pessoas insistem usá-los em conjunto, por exemplo, para Angular existe o **ngx-materialize** para utilizar o Materialize: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-materialize

Comment: ERROR in src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:15:30 - error TS2339: Property 'dropdown' does not exist on type ```'JQuery<HTMLElement>'```.
```$("#dropdown-trigger").dropdown();```
｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: O que me deixa mais confuso é que, segundo a documentação do Materialize, isso por si só seria o suficiente pra fazer o menu funcionar

Comment: Só isto basta, talvez com Angular não. Sabe que o Materialize funciona com Javascript puro tbm né?!

Comment: vi o javascript no site, e fiquei com uma dúvida nesse trecho: ```var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);```. O que é aquela classe ```M```, de onde é chamado o Dropdown.init (trecho extraído de https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html)? Inclusive o TypeScript acusa erro ao procurar a classe.

Comment: M é de Materialize, é tipo um comando: Materialize vai iniciar o componente Dropdown. Tem que ver em qual escopo está declarando a variável instance, como disse, mexer com algo que não foi feito para aquilo é bem ruim mesmo.

Comment: Deu certo, removi o jQuery e  importei o Materialize e a função passou a responder. Também tinha um conflito com o @types/materialize-css que gerava erro ao chamar ele sem o jQuery, mas foi só reinstalar. Obrigado.

Comment: Legal Arthur, sucesso aí.

Comment: Olá viva, partilha numa resposta nova a tua própria solução com o excerto de código o mais completo possível, assim poderás ajudar alguém no futuro tal como é objetivo desta plataforma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer o menu funcionar, mas, pra isso, tive que abrir mão do JQuery. Assim como o @LeAndrade mencionou nos comentários, não consegui usando o JQuery, pois ele estava entrando em conflito com o Angular, e tive que fazer usando JavaScript puro.

Assim, a classe que criei ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
});
export class MyClass extends OnInit{
    constructor( /* dependências */ ){}

    ngOnInit(){ }
}
```

A função do event listener ficou do lado de fora da classe pois parecia fazer mais sentido semântico (não sei se fiz corretamente, mas ok, funciona). Por fim, foi necessário adicionar a linha de import no início do arquivo:

```
import * as M from 'materialize-css';
```

Lembrando que já possuo o arquivo `angular.json` configurado para importar o Materialize, como mostrado abaixo:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
]
```

Espero ter ajudado.