# Erro ao integrar template ao Angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-7

Olá, estou com um problema: Estou integrando uma template que funciona em jQuery, css3 e html5. Adicionei ele no node_modules e referenciei os scripts no angular.json. O css da template está funcionando normalmente, mas nenhuma função de javascript/jquery está funcionando, alguém pode me auxiliar?

Referenciamento :

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/altair/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/assets/js/uikit_htmleditor_custom.js",
          "src/assets/bower_components/uikit/uikit.js",
          "src/assets/assets/js/common.min.js",
          "src/assets/assets/js/uikit_custom.min.js",
          "src/assets/assets/js/kendoui_custom.min.js",
          "src/assets/assets/js/altair_admin_common.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411207/como-fazer-menu-dropdown-no-angular-com-materialize-css?noredirect=1#comment803260_411207

Comment: Boa tarde, eu já dei uma lida e tentei aplicar esse método, mas não funcionou. Nada que utiliza o arquivo principal.js da template está funcionando...

Answer (score 0):

Pra usar o jquery

```
 npm install jquery --save
```

no angular.json

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

para usar o Jquery, você deve importar em qualquer component que você queria usar

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Esse exemplo usa o app-rot no seu component

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  public ngOnInit()
  {
    //jQuery code
        });
    });
  }
}
```

de uma olhada na [documentação oficial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib#global-library-installation)

Comment: Já fiz tudo isso, o jquery em si está funcionando, mas o código de minha template não funciona. Nenhum evento funciona, sidebar não funciona, nada, nada... tá complicado :/

Comment: você pode me passar o código do repositorio no github? que baixo e te ajudo a resolver

Comment: O template é gigante, tem muito código... você tem algum meio para contato?

Comment: Fiz o deploy do projeto: https://github.com/andrerebonato/error-angular

Comment: Está faltando o package.json no repositório que você enviou

Comment: você consegue iniciar um novo projeto e importar o bower_components e assets da pasta src/assets ??

Comment: sim... do jeito que você colocou mesmo...  no scripts do angular.json, se você colocar os scripts, não precisa importar no index.html... ex: "scripts": [ "src/assets/bower_components/moment/moment.js"]

Comment: Então, mas infelizmente não funcionou de nenhuma das formas, você conseguiu?

Comment: Realmente, consegui importar algumas das dependências, mas a pasta bower_module não tem algumas outras. Tive problemas principalmente com o codemirror. Vou investigar mais a fundo e te digo caso eu consiga

Comment: Beleza, fico no aguardo companheiro, até agora não consegui solucionar também...

Comment: Onde você baixou esse template? De repente alguma documentação poderia ajudar, ou até mesmo a versão original. Vi que já está com algumas dependências do bower, mas o index.html faz referência à bibliotecas que não estão disponíves no bower_components. Esse é o template original?